# Why c++ .find() method is not working properly?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a code to determine how many characters in string s are also in j

Here is my code:

```
string j,s;
cin >> j >>s;
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<j.size();++i){
    if(s.find(j[i])){
        ++count;
    }
}
cout << count+1 << endl;
```

The problem is that s.find is not work for j[0] and
When a user enters none as string s it perceives it to be the keyword none.

How can I fix this?
I am using clang 13.0.0
GNU nano 6.0 as my editor

Comment: "a user enters none as string s it perceives it to be the keyword none." that's a faulty assumption from your part. That's not what is happening. Use a debugger to see exactly what is happening in the code instead of guessing.

Comment: @bolov yes, you were right it was not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string::find` does not return a boolean, but the position of the matching character (from 0 to `size()-1`) or string::npos if it doesn't find anything.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Use `if(s.find(j[i]) != std::string::npos)` instead.

Comment: It seems to solve most of the problem but for e.g. if user enters what in j and none in s it returns 4 why?

Comment: Now, it's working thank you

Comment: Be really careful about out-of-bounds accesses in `j` and `s`. Use for `i < std::min(j.size(), s.size())` as your `for` condition instead.

Answer (score 2):

From [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)'s documentation:

> **Return value**
>
> Position of the first character of the found substring or `npos` if no such substring is found.

So, test should be:

```
if (s.find(j[i]) != std::string::npos)
```